# Math power doesn't work correctly in formula in php

Tags: php, math, operators, calc

I am trying to add this formula into my PHP script:

```
50x^(y−10)
```

In this example: `x = 1.1` and `y = 99` which makes the formula:

```
50*1.1^(99-10)
```

This should return `~241501.0278` as result. But when I apply this in PHP, I only get `110` as output.

```
$vocMultiplier = 1.1;
$startSkill = 99;
$amountOfHits = 50 * $vocMultiplier ^($startSkill - 10);
echo $amountOfHits;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Reference: [here](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=50*1.1%5E%2899-10%29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mis-interpreting the `^` symbol for the `pow` function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php

`^` is the Bitwise Exclusive Or operator.

Comment: Oh I see! `$amountOfHits = 50 * pow($vocMultiplier, $startSkill - 10);` that works! Thanks!